# problemas con boton de submit

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2017

Estoy atravesando una dificultad con mi codigo de javascript para que el boton realiza el llamado del click. he cambiado el codigo varias veces y no me hace nada.
podrian ayudarme po explicarme que tengo mal
aqui les dejo el codigo:::

```
<body>
    <form>
        <p><h2>Selecciona 1 o más de los siguientes artículos</h2></p>
        <br><br>
        <hr>
        <input type="checkbox" name="laptop"> Allienware $1,250.00
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="laptop"> OMEN $750.00
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="laptop"> Legion $895.00
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="laptop"> Predator $1,000.00
        <br><br>
        <hr />
        <button id="sButton" type="submit"> Submit</button>
        <p id="Total"></p>
    </form>
    <script>
        // función para añadir valor a los "checkbox" y mostrar total
        function calcTotal() {

            var itemTotal = 0;
            var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

            laptop[0] = $1250.00
            laptop[1] = $750.00
            laptop[2] = $895.00
            laptop[3] = $1000.00

        for (var i = 0; i <4; i++) {
            if (items[i].checked) {
                itemTotal += (items[i].value * 1);
            }   

        }
            document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = "El total de su orden es $" + itemTotal + ".00";

        // añadir detector de eventos compatible hacai atras al toón enviar
        var submitButton = document.activeElementById("sButton");
        if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
        }
        else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
            submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
        }



    </script>
```

Comment: Tu problema podría estar en el HTML, deberías colocarlo

Comment: Y coloca también la función correctamente, tal y como lo has puesto falta el `}` de cierre de la función.

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo que publicas no hay relacion entre el `submit` y la funcionalidad que quieres ejecutar en `javascript`.

Si la idea es realizar una accion en codigo cliente deberias usar un `type=button` y no un `type=submit`

Entonces en el html utilizar

```
<button id="sButton" type="button" onclick="calcTotal()"> Submit</button>
```

Al usar el `onclick` se ejecutara la accion pero no tendras una llamada al servidor en el `submit` ya que esto actualizaria la pagina y perderias el calculo que realices.

Si quieres adjuntar un evento desde codigo cliente, recomendaria evalues si usas la seleccion del elemento html, quizas usando `getElementById()`

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("sButton");
```